# Why did certain fields came back 0 when having values using tablet API to write data in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: tablet, apache-iotdb, iotdb

When I use `tablet` API to write data in Apache IoTDB, for the same timestamp and the same time series data point, only one of the 12 field values is correctly inserted, and other fields all reported 0 when actually having values. I have fields in this time series that may be 0, but it should not be all of them. Why did this happened and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing data in Apache IoTDB using `tablet`, if only one field in a row has certain value, other columns need to be `markedNull` using `private static void insertTabletWithNullValues()` command in `Session`.